# How go get everything from between parenthesis in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, preg-match

```
Array(
[1] => put returns (between) paragraphs
[2] => (for) linebreak (add) 2 spaces at end
[3] => indent code by 4 (spaces!)
[4] => to make links
)
```

Want to get text inside brackets (for each value):

1. **take only first match**
2. **remove this match from the value**
3. **write all matches to new array**

After function arrays should look like:

```
Array(
[1] => put returns paragraphs
[2] => linebreak (add) 2 spaces at end
[3] => indent code by 4
[4] => to make links
)
Array(
[1] => between
[2] => for
[3] => spaces!
[4] => 
)
```

**What is the solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the regular expression `/\((\([^()]*\)|[^()]*)\)/` (this will match one or two pairs of parentheses) together with [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
$matches = array();
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $parts = preg_split('/\((\([^()]*\)|[^()]*)\)/', $value, 2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    if (count($parts) > 1) {
        $matches[] = current(array_splice($parts, 1, 1));
        $value = implode('', $parts);
    }
}
```

Using `preg_split` with *PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE* flag set will contain the matched separators in the result array. So a match was found, there are at least three parts. In that case the second member is the one we are looking for. That member is removed with [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice) that does also return the array of removed members. To get the removed member, [`current`](http://php.net/current) is used on the return value of `array_splice`. The remaining members are then put back together.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant `(between)` and not `((between))`

```
$arr = array(
                0 => 'put returns (between) paragraphs',
                1 => '(for) linebreak (add) 2 spaces at end',
                2 => 'indent code by 4 (spaces!)',
                3 => 'to make links');
var_dump($arr);

$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $key => &$str) {
        if(preg_match('/(\(.*?\))/',$str,$m)) {
                $new_arr[] = $m[1]; 
                $str = preg_replace('/\(.*?\)/','',$str,1);
        }   
        else {
                $new_arr[] = ''; 
        }   
}
var_dump($arr);
var_dump($new_arr);
```

[Working link](http://www.ideone.com/QKrPW)